# design and implement interface to track ranges using python

Tags: python

1: Add range - Tracked the supplied input range. Adding a range that partially overlaps with the currently tracked ranges should track any numbers in the added range that are not already tracked.

```
e.g. AddRange(10,180)- start tracking range 10-180
AddRange(150,200)- start tracking range 150-200
AddRange(250,500) - start tracking range 250-500
```

**Possible solution**

```
def merge_ranges(ranges):
    ranges = iter(sorted(ranges))
    current_start, current_stop = next(ranges)
    for start, stop in ranges:
        if start > current_stop:
        # Gap between segments: output current segment and start a new one.
            yield current_start, current_stop
            current_start, current_stop = start, stop
        else:
        # Segments adjacent or overlapping: merge.
            current_stop = max(current_stop, stop)
    yield current_start, current_stop
```

2: Remove range: Remove the supplied range of numbers from those being tacked. A remove range operation for a partially tracked range should remove all numbers in that range that are already tracked.

```
e.g. Ranges tracked [10-200],[250-500]

RemoveRange(50,150) - stop tracking range 50-150 ([10-149], [151-200],[250-500])
RemoveRange(400,600) - stop tracking range 400-500 ([10-49],[250-399])
Remove range(600,800) - no-op as none of the ranges were tracked
```

**Possible solution**

```
def remove_overlap(rs):
    rs.sort()
    def process (rs,deviation):
        start = len(rs) - deviation - 1
        if start < 1:
            return rs
        if rs[start][0] > rs[start-1][1]:
            return process(rs,deviation+1)
        else:
            rs[start-1] = ((rs[start][0],rs[start-1][0])[rs[start-1][0] < rs[start][0]],(rs[start][1],rs[start-1][1])[rs[start-1][1] > rs[start][1]])
            del rs[start]
            return process(rs,0)
    return process(rs,0)
```

3 Query range: return true if entire range is being tracked; false otherwise

```
e.g QueryRange(50,100) - returns True
QueryRange(180,300) - returns False (only part of the range is being tracked)
QueryRange (600,100)- returns False(not tracked at all)
```

How to **implement this?**

Also, need to implement the whole thing in an object oriented way:

Pseudo code:

```
class RangeModule:
    def AddRange(self, lower, upper):
        pass

    def QueryRange(self, lower, upper):
        return True

    def RemoveRange(self, lower, upper):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a list of pairs (ranges) sorted by starting point. It's your responsibility to ensure that the ranges don't overlap, and that they aren't adjacent to each other - if they're adjacent, merge them.

Because they are sorted, and don't overlap, you can quickly find overlaps with an input range. Use this to handle adding, querying, and removing.